# check to see if a char array begins with certain characers

Tags: c

The code I need to write has the user input a mRna strand which is stored in a char array. This mRNa strand must start with the characters 'a','u','g'. I can't figure out how to validate whether that is true. I thought about getting the sum of the integer values and testing that but I cannot do that because it matches the letters of another 3 letters that can be entered.

also,  each three letters translates to an amino acid. I dont know how to take each three letters and translate it.

An example for my second question
The mRNA string is 
auguuuauu

aug codes for methionine.

uuu codes for phenylalaine.

auu codes for isoleucine.

so the program would go down the line reading each group of 3 and translating it. the values would then be stored in a character array. The way I'm thinking of doing this is making a loop that would store 3 values at a time into a char array. I dont know how to take that char array analyze what that value is and change it to what it needs to be. Once its changed i would just strcat it to the end.

Comment: I would like to see Your thought in code.

Comment: You're having trouble writing an `if` clause with three sub-conditions??

Comment: Are you aware of the `==` equality test operator and the `&&` operator  for combining boolean expressions? This should be able to get you what you need.

Comment: You don't even need the `&&` if you call `strncmp`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Sure, but if OP is unable to come up with the `&&` solution, I think it'd be a worthwhile exercise to get that working (and not think some black magic is going on in `strncmp` that they wouldn't be able to reproduce)

Comment: Of course you do not want the simple sum of the first three characters. You would need a hash function to reduce the collisions, a simple checksum is insufficient. But hashing probably is not a good approach for such a simple use case, if you had longer sequences you might consider this instead of comparing the characters one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you know it's the first three, you can always do this:

```
char *strand;

// load string in there

if (3 <= strlen(strand) && ( strncmp("aug",strand,3) == 0 )) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And presto, you have your confirmation.

If you need to handle different ordering, maybe you could clarify your question.

Edit:

If you need one of each:

```
char *strand;

// load string in there

if (3 <= strlen(strand) && 
      (   strncmp("aug",strand,3) == 0
       || strncmp("agu",strand,3) == 0
       || strncmp("gau",strand,3) == 0
       || strncmp("gua",strand,3) == 0
       || strncmp("uga",strand,3) == 0
       || strncmp("uag",strand,3) == 0 )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you need any permutation of those letters:

```
char *strand;
int matchCount = 0;

// load string in there

if (3 <= strlen(strand))
{
    switch (strand[0])
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'u':
        case 'g':
            matchCount++;
            break:
    }
    switch (strand[1])
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'u':
        case 'g':
            matchCount++;
            break:
    }
    switch (strand[2])
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'u':
        case 'g':
            matchCount++;
            break:
    }
}

if (3 == matchCount) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Ok, given your update, here's a solution to your second question.

```
#define METHIONINE    "aug"
#define PHENYLALAINE  "uuu"
#define ISOLEUCINE    "auu"

#define UNDEFINEDVALUE     0
#define METHIONINEVALUE    1
#define PHENYLALAINEVALUE  2
#define ISOLEUCINEVALUE    3

#define NUMBEROFACIDS  256

char *strand,*strandItr;
int aminoAcidList[NUMBEROFACIDS]={UNDEFINEDVALUE};
int aminoAcidCount = 0;
unsigned int i = 0;

// load string in there

if ((strlen(strand) % 3)) != 0)
{
    // your string doesn't only have these three-long amino acids
}

aminoAcidCount = strlen(strand)/3;

for (i = 0; i < aminoAcidCount; i++)
{
    if (strncmp(METHIONINE,(strand + i*3),3) == 0)
    {
        aminoAcidList[i] = METHIONINEVALUE;
    }
    else if (strncmp(PHENYLALAINE,(strand + i*3),3) == 0)
    {
        aminoAcidList[i] = PHENYLALAINEVALUE;
    }
    else if (strncmp(ISOLEUCINE,(strand + i*3),3) == 0)
    {
        aminoAcidList[i] = ISOLEUCINEVALUE;
    }
}

// do other stuff

for (i = 0; i < aminoAcidCount; i++)
{
    switch (aminoAcidList[i])
    {
        case METHIONINEVALUE:
            printf ("Methionine\n");
            break;
        case PHENYLALAINEVALUE:
            printf ("Phenylalaine\n");
            break;
        case ISOLEUCINEVALUE:
            printf ("Isoleucine\n");
            break;
        case UNDEFINEDVALUE:
        default:
            printf ("Unknown amino acid\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: strncmp is a better solution

Comment: Yup, it is.  Changed it - thanks :)

Comment: The expression `3 >= strlen(strand)` checks that the length of the string is equal to or less than 3. You want to check if the string is greater than or equal to 3, so `strlen(strand) >= 3`, or if you insist on writing it the other way around, `3 <= strlen(strand)`.

Comment: Ten year old bug but wow, good catch. :) Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strncmp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) to compare the start of two strings:

```
if (strncmp(mRNAstrand, "aug", 3) == 0)
```

Comment: Would be good to check the length first with `if (strlen(mRNAstrand) >= 3)` no?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, just write:

```
if (!(*mRna == 'a' || *mRna == 'u' || *mRna == 'g'))
    //Handle wrong array
```

You should provide a code example for your second problem to make it a bit clearer what you are having trouble with though.

Comment: I think OP wants to know if the first three characters are "aug", not that the first character is one of 'a','u','g'.